# Scraping second page in Python Yields Different Data Than Browsing to Second Page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm attempting to scrape some data from www.ksl.com/auto/ using Python Requests and Beautiful Soup. I'm able to get the results from the first search page but not subsequent pages. When I request the second page using the same URL Chrome constructs when I click the "Next" button on the page, I get a set of results that no longer matches my search query. I've found other questions on Stack Overflow that discuss Ajax calls that load subsequent pages, and using Chrome's Developer tools to examine the request. But, none of that has helped me with this problem -- which I've had on other sites as well.

Here is an [example query](https://www.ksl.com/auto/search/index?keyword=&make%5B%5D=Acura&yearFrom=&yearTo=&mileageFrom=&mileageTo=&priceFrom=&priceTo=&zip=&miles=25&newUsed%5B%5D=All&page=0&sellerType=&postedTime=&titleType=&body=&transmission=&cylinders=&liters=&fuel=&drive=&numberDoors=&exteriorCondition=&interiorCondition=&cx_navSource=hp_search&search.x=63&search.y=8&search=Search%20raquo%3B) that returns only Acuras on the site. When you advance in the browser to the second page, the URL is simply this: https://www.ksl.com/auto/search/index?page=1. When I use Requests to hit those two URLs, the second search results are not Acuras. Is there, perhaps a cookie that my browser is passing back to the server to preserve my filters?

I would appreciate any advice someone can give about how to get subsequent pages of the results I searched for.

Here is the simple code I'm using:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page1 = get('https://www.ksl.com/auto/search/index?keyword=&make%5B%5D=Acura&yearFrom=&yearTo=&mileageFrom=&mileageTo=&priceFrom=&priceTo=&zip=&miles=25&newUsed%5B%5D=All&page=0&sellerType=&postedTime=&titleType=&body=&transmission=&cylinders=&liters=&fuel=&drive=&numberDoors=&exteriorCondition=&interiorCondition=&cx_navSource=hp_search&search.x=63&search.y=8&search=Search+raquo%3B').text
page2 = get('https://www.ksl.com/auto/search/index?page=2').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page1, 'html.parser')
listings = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "srp-listing-body-right" })
listings[0] # An Acura - success!

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2, 'html.parser')
listings2 = soup2.findAll("div", { "class" : "srp-listing-body-right" })
listings2[0] # Not an Acura. :(
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Create a [`Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) object and then call the links. This will maintain your session with the server when you send a call to the next link.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session() # Add this line

page1 = s.get('https://www.ksl.com/auto/search/index?keyword=&make%5B%5D=Acura&yearFrom=&yearTo=&mileageFrom=&mileageTo=&priceFrom=&priceTo=&zip=&miles=25&newUsed%5B%5D=All&page=0&sellerType=&postedTime=&titleType=&body=&transmission=&cylinders=&liters=&fuel=&drive=&numberDoors=&exteriorCondition=&interiorCondition=&cx_navSource=hp_search&search.x=63&search.y=8&search=Search+raquo%3B').text
page2 = s.get('https://www.ksl.com/auto/search/index?page=1').text
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Such a simply solution. I can't believe I couldn't find anywhere via Google!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the website uses cookies so that `https://www.ksl.com/auto/search/index` shows or extends your last search.  More specifically, the search parameters are stored on the server for you particular session cookie, that is, the value of the `PHPSESSID` cookie.

However, instead of passing that cookie around, you can simply always do  full queries (in the sense of the request parameters), each time using a different value for the `page` parameter.

```
https://www.ksl.com/auto/search/index?keyword=&make%5B%5D=Acura&yearFrom=&yearTo=&mileageFrom=&mileageTo=&priceFrom=&priceTo=&zip=&miles=25&newUsed%5B%5D=All&page=0&sellerType=&postedTime=&titleType=&body=&transmission=&cylinders=&liters=&fuel=&drive=&numberDoors=&exteriorCondition=&interiorCondition=&cx_navSource=hp_search&search.x=63&search.y=8&search=Search+raquo%3B
https://www.ksl.com/auto/search/index?keyword=&make%5B%5D=Acura&yearFrom=&yearTo=&mileageFrom=&mileageTo=&priceFrom=&priceTo=&zip=&miles=25&newUsed%5B%5D=All&page=1&sellerType=&postedTime=&titleType=&body=&transmission=&cylinders=&liters=&fuel=&drive=&numberDoors=&exteriorCondition=&interiorCondition=&cx_navSource=hp_search&search.x=63&search.y=8&search=Search+raquo%3B
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and alternative solution!